# Why can’t I add the score like this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I’ve been trying to make a little survival prototype, but I can’t figure out the very basic thing I need for this project, picking up things. I wrote the code below (I’m no programmer) but it does NOTHING, and I just can’t figure out why. It’s a 2D 4 directional movement survival game.

I’ve rewrtitten the whole code a lot of times, tried out all of the methods I thought of. and I just don’t know what to do next.

Also, from the debug it seems the 2 colliders don’t event collide? I have no idea why.

So, in answers, someone sayed "Hey, use OnTriggerRemain2D!" which I did...later It was pointed out to me in the comments under this post, this function does no exist. Please help, I’m beggining to be desperate.

So, progress, debug shows they collide and they know it, but they don’t seem to add the point to the text i’ve created, and I don’t think it registered the keyboard pressing, but I’m getting close.

IT ALMOST WORKS, It adds only when moving, and in large quantities, but it works, and I’m happy for It.

**Code for the player**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HracMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed = 1000f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movementDirection;
    public LogicManager logic;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        logic = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Logic").GetComponent<LogicManager>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movementDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = movementDirection * playerSpeed;
    }
        void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ker") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            logic.addStick();
            Debug.Log("touching");
        }
    }

}
```

**Code for the Logic Manager**

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class LogicManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int score = 0;
        public Text scoreText;
    
        void Start()
        {
            
        }
    
        public void addStick()
        {
            score = score + 1;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging. Is `OnCollisionEnter2D` ever called? If it is are the conditions you're using true? Easy to see with two added log statements.

Comment: Well, It seems like It isn’t. I’ve added a line of code to print "touching" when it’s called, but it never did, and I also changed It to trigger, because it made more sense to me. Well, now I’m even more confused.

Comment: Are your colliders **2D** colliders (e.g., CapsuleCollider**2D** instead of CapsuleCollider)?

Comment: `OnTriggerRemain2D` doesn't exist .. do you mean [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html)? ... After your various editing of your code in question some of the answers below are now invalid / seemingly off-topic and it is not clear to me what your actual intend is ..

Comment: @derHugo I’m just confused right now. I’ve been trying to figure this out and posted this as just the last resort option, to get my answer, and so I did everything that was provided, every answer I tried, NOTHING. I’m gonna rewrite the OnTriggerRemain2D to stay, this function was in one of the answers, that’s why it’s in my code.

Comment: @Slonica well the confusion begins with you modifying your **question** with code used from the **answers** ... you question should remain the code you originally asked about ... otherwise according answers make no sense anymore

Comment: @derHugo Yeah I’m sorry man, I’m using this site for the firts time, thanks for this, gonna try to do it like this/better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the code, and let's assume `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called (which you could check by moving the print outside the if statement), you are comparing your layer to 3, which **will never be true**.

You can use `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default")` instead.

If you want to know why, it's because Unity's layers are using a [Flag system](https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/10_w43/194874/Fig1-2.jpg).
So :
`Layer1 = 0, Layer2 = 1, Layer3 = 2, Layer4 = 4, Layer5 = 8, etc.`
With **flags**, 3 would mean **Layer2 AND Layer3**, but GameObject can only have one layer at a time.

#### Side Note:

In your case, **Tags** would be better to use than Layers. It would look like this *(replace "Player" with your tag)*:

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        logic.addStick();
        print("touching");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be best answered with an example.

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log($"OnTriggerEnter2D. layer: {collision.gameObject.layer}\nSpacebar pressed: {Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)}");
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        logic.addStick();
        Debug.Log("touching");
    }
}
```

The issue you might start noticing is that the `OnTriggerEnter2D` event happens once, for a fraction of a second, and when you use that in conjunction with `Input.GetKeyDown`, which ALSO occurs in one frame, for a fraction of a second, there's almost no chance in the world that both of those events are going to be true at the same time.

I would think that you want to use (a) `OnTriggerStay2D` instead, OR use (b) `Input.GetKey`. If you are checking if the object is "remaining" in the trigger, you have plenty of time to press the space bar. Alternatively, if you use GetKey, you could be pressing the space bar well before you enter the trigger, and your condition will be satisfied.

To recap, (a)

```cs
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log($"OnTriggerStay2D. layer: {collision.gameObject.layer}\nSpacebar pressed: {Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)}");
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        logic.addStick();
        Debug.Log("touching");
    }
}
```

or (b)

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log($"OnTriggerEnter2D. layer: {collision.gameObject.layer}\nSpacebar pressed: {Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)}");
    if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        logic.addStick();
        Debug.Log("touching");
    }
}
```

Comment: `a) OnTriggerRemain2D` doesn't exist .... do you mean [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) ..?